# Do you guys know why when i run a script, it doesn't do as it's supposed to but when i do in the inspector, it works?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

Im making a gun pickup script, but when carrying the gun i don't want it to move from the guncontainer so i constrained its position, but when i run the script, it shows it as constrained in the inspector, but still moves. Afterwards when i try the same thing except i do it "physicly" only using the inspecter to check on the constrains, it works... help

Answer (score 0):

you need to check that your gun container is also constrained, because if that moves the gun will also move.

Comment: But when i did all the work via the inspector, it worked?

Comment: It Should work yes, also next time please make sure to ask the question properly. such as adding the script and/or adding screenshots of the problem. thank you